# Windows 8.1 sometimes does not recognize USB 2.0 connection on the front port

Tags: windows, usb, windows-8.1, usb-2

Windows 8.1 sometimes does not recognize the front USB 2.0 port on my machine. Any device that is connected to the front port are not even turning it’s light on. My mouse and keyboard work well and they are connected to USB 2.0 port on the back of the machine.

After restarting my system, USB 2.0 works again so it is not a wiring/connection issue that is comming from the case nor the motherboard issue. I think there is something wrong with the z77 chipset; does it even support Windows 8.1? I would be really surprised if it’s not. Everything works with Windows 7 so what’s the problem with Windows 8.1 and how do I fix it?

Comment: Are your drivers up to date?

Comment: yes, they are..

Answer (score 0):

This problem is probably because of a buggy driver. Try checking Disk Management for your issue. This can be achieved by navigating to:

- Control Panel > System and Security > Administrative Tools > Computer Management
- Then on the sidebar navigate to Storage>Disk Management.
- If it is just not showing under My PC then it will show up here.
- If it still is not showing, Try looking into errors with the USB drive.
- Other than that you can try running the Hardware and Devices Troubleshooter.

Comment: the drive is not showen in the disk managment section, drivers are up to date